print-level, print-length variables not working?
Why is my eval-expression output being truncated despite setting all the print-level and print-length variables to a very high value?
(setf print-level 99999999999999 
      print-length 99999999999999 
      eval-expression-print-length 99999999999999
      eval-expression-print-level 99999999999999
      eval-expression-print-maximum-character 9999999)

Screencast reproducing the problem:
screencast
emacs version: GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.38, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2024-06-25, modified by Debian

Did you try emacs -Q?

Maybe you also need to set edebug-print-level and edebug-print-length. And if you want unlimited, say so: set them all to nil.

@NickD Yes, I didn't realize that edebug has a separate set of print-length-related variables.

When in doubt, read the help:
print-level is a variable defined in C source code.

Value
nil

Documentation
Maximum depth of list nesting to print before abbreviating.

A value of nil means no limit.  See also eval-expression-print-level.

And then following the link we see:
eval-expression-print-level is a customizable variable defined in
simple.el.gz.

Value
4

Documentation
Value for print-level while printing value in eval-expression.

A value of nil means no limit.


This doesn't answer OP's question.
